# VBA ADO insert data to Access table from MySQL table

Tags: vba, ms-access

i want to add info from MySQL server to Access table via Access VBA ADO

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection

cnn.Open "WP1"

CurrentDb.Execute ("delete * from wp_postmeta1;")

cnn.Execute ("INSERT INTO wp_postmeta1 ( meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value ) in '" & CurrentProject.Connection & "' " & _
             "SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_id, wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value " & _
             "FROM wp_postmeta;")
```

Comment: and the code is not working, how to fix it?

Comment: Code is in Access connecting to MySQL? What is WP1? Review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919976/ms-access-to-mysql-connection

Comment: attach both tables to your Access front-end, then treat them  both like Access tables and use good ol' DAO, or just a simple query.

Comment: DAO has question with MySQL server timeout, while ado provide possibility to connect more often, how to connect to my base from ADO

Comment: here is possible solution for each row (https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/524214-visual-basic-applications-joining-multiple-recordets-multiple-databases.html), which is slow, how to insert all table?

Comment: although i am not a big fan of linked tables, you can link to your sql server table, and then just write regular queries in access to transfer the rows referencing that linked table. another option is to create a pass-through query, which i prefer.. the pass through query would read the table in sql server, and you would then have another local query in access that references the pass-through to transfer to your local table, both should however perform better than what you are trying to do with ADO, and would, or should be code free

Comment: many thanks for All comments/advises, i moved all to MySQL and ADO queries in VBA, speed is fantastic: 1sec per report (before was 7min) :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by adding connection string:

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection    
cnn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};Server=localhost;port=3306;Database=dbo;User=root;pwd=XXXX;Option=3"
cnn.Open

Do While cnn.State <> 1
   DoEvents
   If cnn.State = 0 Then Exit Sub
Loop
```